# Tailwind Width: 0px; automatically added to style property of div

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am making a web application using Next.JS and Tailwind for styling. I would like to map over some "accords" for a perfume giving them each variable widths by reading the `size` property of each `accord` which is a string. I am interpolating this into the Tailwind class of each div like so:

```js
className={`text-center w-${accord.size} rounded-r-2xl`}
```

I also have a style property which does not involve a width:

```js
style={{ backgroundColor: accordsData[accord.accord].color }}
```

When this code is rendered in the browser it returns the correct class for each div however widths are not rendered because it automatically adds `width: 0px;` to the style:

```html
<div class="text-center w-100 rounded-r-2xl" style="background-color: rgb(204, 51, 0); width: 0px;">...</div>
```

I would like my application to not add this extra style and to instead use the width from the Tailwind class.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: If you modify the div to a div without any classes/styles, would the width 0 stay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was being silly, I forgot to mention I am also using [Framer Motion](https://www.framer.com/motion/) and so I uncovered with some debugging that the width was being set to 0 by that.

Answer (score 2):

Are you adding width values that are included in tailwind's default width settings? Or do you have a custom width set up in your *tailwind.config.js* file?

If you don't and you're trying to set an arbitrary value you could look at Tailwind's documentation.

According to the documentation of Tailwind:

***Arbitrary values***
*If you need to use a one-off width value that doesn’t make sense to include in your theme, use square brackets to generate a property on the fly using any arbitrary value.*

```html
<div class="w-[32rem]">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

You would include your width in the [] like so:

```html
<div class={`w-[${accord.size}]`}>
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Hope this helps!